# Extract all URLs from the json object in Python

Tags: python

I have a long json object which contains URL links in the value, these links can be at any depth and with any key. The depth and key is not known. Ex.,

```
data = {
  "name": "John Doe",
  "a": "https:/example.com",
  "b": {
    "c": "https://example.com/path",
    "d": {
      "e": "https://example.com/abc/?q=u",
    }
  }
}
```

I want to extract all links in a list like

```
links = ["https://example.com", "https://example.com/path", "https://example.com/abc/?q=u"]
```

**How can I extract all the links from the object using Python?**

Comment: how do you identify urls? Is it okay to assume they all start with "HTTP"?

Comment: Yes, they all wll start from `http` or `https`. Any string without these protocols will not be treated as valid URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution:

```py
def extract_urls(d):
    urls = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, str) and v.lower().startswith("http"):
            urls.append(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            urls.extend(etract_urls(v))
    return urls

extract_urls(data)
```

Output:

```
['https:/example.com',
 'https://example.com/path',
 'https://example.com/abc/?q=u']
```

Comment: There's a typo in this answer; someone else edited the function to be called extract_urls (it was originally called etract_urls) to fix a typo, but didn't update the recursive function. The recursive function is still (incorrectly) calling etract_urls.